# Writing values in the next column (cell to the right) if current column (cell) is not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some simple code that gets & sets data from/to different sheets.

Trouble is, I'd like to keep the data from previous runnings, but of course every time I run the script it overwrites the previous data.

Any IF statement simply posts the same value twice. What do I need to do?

Many thanks.

```
    //get values from tab 1 table
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var gcls = s.getRange(6, 10, 4).getValues();

  //write values in tab 2
  var gSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking');
  var gcells = gSheet.getRange(5, 1, 4);
  gcells.setValues(gcls);
```

Comment: Quick question - does your second sheet have headers for the columns or is each new column completely empty?

Comment: Welcome. There is important information missing from your question - principally, what is the relationship between the source range and the archive destination range, but also the layout of your spreadsheet, the data elements, and the spreadsheet itself. One example: your source range is J6:J9 but the archive goes to A5:A8 - what's the logic behind this?  You need to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to provide more and meaningful information. In addition, please share you spreadsheet.

Comment: The second sheet has no headers or anything like that. Its simply an archive sheet that I run a Sparkline to. I've tried .getLastColumn but it just posts to column P eachtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to write one column of data from one sheet to another, and not override the columns you wrote in previous runs but instead you want to write the data in the next blank column.

You can iterate column by column (until 256 which is the maximum number of columns for sheet) through the range of rows where you want to write, in this case 4 rows starting from the 5th row and the first column for the first iteration, using the isBlank function [1] in an if statement you can check if the range is empty and write on it.

I tested the following code and worked as you want:

```
function test3() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var gcls = s.getRange(6, 10, 4).getValues();

  //write values in tab 2  
  var gSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking');

  //Loop until finds empty range
  for(i=1; i<=256; i++) {
    // Warning: Be aware that getRange retrieves a Range type, not a cell. For more info check [2] 
    var gcells = gSheet.getRange(5, i, 4);
    if (gcells.isBlank()) {
       gcells.setValues(gcls);
       break;
    } 
  } 
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows

Comment: That's exactly right, thanks.  I'd tried a loop previously and it just posted it to the end value of the loop. I didn't know this "break" statement.  Thanks for this  :)